# Display Custom options on right side of image

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, product-view, drop-downs

You can see text "MEN" & drop-down **custom options** below image

[image]

You can see text "MEN" & drop-down options on right side of image

[image]

i want to display "MEN" & drop-down options on right side of image for link1.

i am 100% sure, there is same theme and configuration for both products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to : Catalog > Products.
2. Edit `Together Forever` product.
3. Select `Design` Tab
4. Change `Display product options in` select box to `Product Info Column`
5. Save

Comment: no words, i am speechless....